# DataBinding deserialized json array

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, reddit

I am relatively new to C#, silverlight and the whole data binding paradigm. I have been working on a little test app that pulls data from reddit via their [API](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/API) using Json.Net. Anyways, I get the data into my application just fine, but now I am having trouble with pushing the data into the UI. I have tried several different configurations to no avail. Anyways, the code is here:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    string json = "";
    RootObject topic { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBlock1.Text = "Retrieving...";
        string url = @"http://www.reddit.com/r/all.json";
        HttpWebRequest hWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        hWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        hWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(Response_Completed, hWebRequest);
    }
    public void Response_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            topic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            this.DataContext = topic.data.children[0].data.title;
            textBlock1.Text = "Done.";
        });
    }
```

That is the main part of my code. The remaining classes are here, and they are for the deserialization of the JSON the reddit API provides.

```
public class MediaEmbed
    {
        public string content { get; set; }
        public int? width { get; set; }
        public bool? scrolling { get; set; }
        public int? height { get; set; }
    }
    public class Oembed
    {
        public string provider_url { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string author_name { get; set; }
        public int height { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string html { get; set; }
        public int thumbnail_width { get; set; }
        public string version { get; set; }
        public string provider_name { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int thumbnail_height { get; set; }
        public string author_url { get; set; }
    }
    public class Media
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Oembed oembed { get; set; }
    }
    public class Data2
    {
        public string domain { get; set; }
        public MediaEmbed media_embed { get; set; }
        public object levenshtein { get; set; }
        public string subreddit { get; set; }
        public string selftext_html { get; set; }
        public string selftext { get; set; }
        public object likes { get; set; }
        public bool saved { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public bool clicked { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public Media media { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public bool over_18 { get; set; }
        public bool hidden { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string subreddit_id { get; set; }
        public string author_flair_css_class { get; set; }
        public int downs { get; set; }
        public bool is_self { get; set; }
        public string permalink { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double created { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string author_flair_text { get; set; }
        public string author { get; set; }
        public double created_utc { get; set; }
        public int num_comments { get; set; }
        public int ups { get; set; }
    }
    public class Child
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public Data2 data { get; set; }
    }
    public class Data
    {
        public string modhash { get; set; }
        public Child[] children { get; set; }
        public string after { get; set; }
        public object before { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public Data data { get; set; }
    }       
}
```

Let's say that the XAML UI stuff looks like this

```
            <ListBox>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="TitleInfo" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

The titles are contained inside of the instance of RootObject called topic. So the way to grab the titles would be

```
topic.data.children[0].data.title;
```

However, I have almost no idea how I can bind that to these text boxes or a listbox..I know a datacontext must be set and these items can be binded via code as opposed to xaml, but I can't figure out any elegant way to do this. Any help? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, from the looks of things.  Your issue is that you are trying to set the DataContext of the whole page to be a single title from one record (`this.DataContext = topic.data.children[0].data.title;` ) - that's probably not what you mean to do...

To get the data into your ListBox, you have 2 options - you can explicitly set the ItemsSource of the ListBox like so

```
myListBox.ItemsSource = topic.data.children;
```

and then update the XAML to show the data from that point in the object graph...

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleInfo" Text="{Binding data.title}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" Text="{Binding data.author}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

However, if you are looking to use data elsewhere in the page, you will probably want to set the DataContext for the whole page.

```
DataContext = topic;
```

and set your XAML on the ListBox to something slightly different...

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding data.children}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleInfo" Text="{Binding data.title}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" Text="{Binding data.author}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was looking for. The way I tried to define the data context wasn't meant to be posted here, it was more of a stab in the dark that I knew probably wouldn't work and  forgot to delete. Anyways, I had looked into data binding looking for these kinds of examples, but found nothing. It works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to implement [MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) pattern if you want to deal with DataBinidng.

In the meantime, here is a fix of your example:

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string json = "";
    private RootObject topic;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public RootObject Topic 
    { 
        get
        {
            return this.topic;
        }
        set
        {
            this.topic = value;
            var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Topic"));
            }
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ...
    }
    public void Response_Completed(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            json = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            this.Topic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
        }
    }
}
```

And an updated xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Topic.data.children}" >
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="TitleInfo" Text="{Binding data.title}" />
                <TextBlock x:Name="AuthorInfo" Text="{Binding data.author}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```